# Magento: add a button to the admin config

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add a button with a backend handler. Here's the code

Admin config: `system.xml`

```
<sync_now_button translate="label">
    <label>Sync Now</label>
    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>                         
    <backend_model><namespace>_<module>/backend_syncnow</backend_model>
    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</sync_now_button>
```

Backend model: `<namespace>/<module>/Model/Syncnow.php`

```
<?php$

class <namespace>_<module>_Backend_Syncnow extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function _afterSave()
    {
        Zend_Debug::dump('sync now');
        exit;
    }
}
```

When I load the section associated with my configuration, I get following error -

```
Invalid config field backend model: <namespace>_<module>/backend_syncnow

Trace:
#0 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/measure9/public_html/demo.smartsearch.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Any pointers what could be wrong with my configuration?

**Update #1:** 
I have managed to solve my issue partially. I changed the class name from `<namespace>_<module>_Backend_Syncnow` to `<namespace>_<module>_Model_Syncnow` and I can see the button on the UI. However, the button does not show text and clicking on the button does not invoke my model.

P.S. `<namespace>` and `<module>` are just placeholders.

Comment: Would I be right to assume you have just swapped out your namespace and module name and are not actually using `<namespace>` and `<module>`?

Comment: Yes. I have some more fields above the button and they appear just fine. I am using those fields in an `Observer` for `catalog_product_after_save` event, so saving and retrieving them works fine too. Updated the question with a node. Thanks.

Comment: Ok well it sounds like you have declared models in your config.xml as you have an observer so that's probably not the issue, you don't need to include the namespace when declaring the 'backend_model' - the module is determined by how you declare your models in your `config.xml` (which is what should be referenced when declaring your `backend_model`).

Comment: @JonathanHussey: If I do not specify `<namespace>` in `<backend_model>` tag, then the site complains that it was unable to load the module.

Comment: Update #1: any log entries? var/log/*.log

Comment: @Detzler: No entries in `var/log/system.log`. Thats the only log file being generated.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento, there is only one button that is defined like the way you do.

Mage/Core/etc/system.xml:

```
<synchronize translate="label comment">
    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>adminhtml/system_config_system_storage_media_synchronize</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    <comment>After selecting a new media storage location, press the Synchronize button
    to transfer all media to that location. Media will not be available in the new
    location until the synchronization process is complete.</comment>
</synchronize>
```

Look at the frontend model class.. maybe you can copy some stuff from:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing "Model" in:

```
class <namespace_<module>_Backend_Syncnow
```

should be

```
class <namespace_<module>_Model_Backend_Syncnow
```

Comment: It worked when I changed the class name to `<namespace>_<module>_Model_Syncnow`. However, now I have different issues, see my update in the question.

Comment: `<frontend_model>` references Block folder not Model.